# How to output the name of a command at the same time when calling a command

Tags: sectioning, layout, primitives, everyshi

I know that using everypar can print some information every time everypar command is called. I want to know whether it is possible to print the name of the command at the same time when the command is called using everypar.
an example：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

One

Two

Three

\paragraph{second}

Four

Five

Six

\end{document}
```

I hope to output a result like this：

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). You could redefine the commands similar to `\let\OldSection\section`, `\let\OldParagraph\paragraph`, `\def\section#1{\OldSection{#1} section:}`, `\def\paragraph#1{\OldParagraph{#1} paragraph:}`. Depending on what your purpose/goal is there may be better solutions avaialble.

Comment: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1NMC.png) as an option?